# Unnecessarily a check / tick mark appearing in my button [ made of anchor tag i.e. link ]

Tags: html, checkmark

I'm using the following code to display a button to clients:

```html
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
style="border-collapse:collapse; background:#005984; width:auto;">
<tbody>
    <tr style="height: 30px;">
        <td style="height: 30px; padding: 5px 22px;">
            <a class="button-a button-a-primary" href="https://google.in" target="_blank"
                style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">
                Click Here to begin </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** My application sends mails to clients, hence client opens the mail on multilple devices/browsers.
Due to security concerns, No idea as of now, on which environment this issue appearing, will be updated if as I get.

My client is seeing an extra checkmark next to the button:

[image: Image showing the extraneous checkmark inside the button]

I cannot reproduce with same html as above. But somehow the client can and has sent me the previous screenshot.

Comment: Could it be that your client has some browser add-on that checks links for them, and is enriching the button with a tick to show it is safe? Do any of your other clients experience this?

Comment: We can speculate.. but if you don't know how to reproduce the issue I'm afraid we're not going to be able to help.

Comment: @GeoffJames : Client opens mail in Gmail. What strange part found that, extra html tags and attributes gets inserted somehow! You can compare below HTML with HTML in question, specially anchor tag where extra span inserted, dont know how.  `<a href="https://google.in"><span style="color: white; font-size: 11.5pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; background-color: rgb(184, 234, 184); text-decoration: none;">Click
Here to begin </span></a>`

Comment: Please add any relevant information that adds context to your question into it then, rather than in a comment. In its current state - as @JeffUK points out - we'd only be speculating what the issue is. I think you need to do some more troubleshooting with the client and ask some more questions to gather more information. Otherwise we're all just clutching at straws. I would start off by asking the question I posed above, as I have a feeling this may lead to the problem; otherwise you need to ask more questions to find the root cause. We on SO can't do that for you, though.

Comment: Tell your client to open gmail in incognito mode and try again

Comment: Our client updated us that he is not facing this issue anymore. So I think, he must have used some "browser add-on" as Goeff suggested , because I reproduced same check marks at my side ( not exactly same ). At last, this issue is no more for me. Thanks for all.